# Keyboard backlight turns on after lock screen/display on

Tags: keyboard, dell, 15.10, lock-screen, keyboard-backlight

I've just upgraded Ubuntu (15.04 to 15.10) and now I'm running into a weird behavior: whenever I lock the screen (using any of Ctrl+Alt+L, Win+L or just clicking on "Lock" in the taskbar menu), the keyboard backlight turns on, even though I always keep it off.

I have no idea where to begin investigating this. It didn't happen in Ubuntu 15.04, and it doesn't seem other people have run into this.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron, if it helps.

**Update:** I later understood that this problem happens whenever the display turns on, which happens right after I lock the screen because of a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1504362). So, these are related events, but the actual cause is the screen turning on.

Comment: Who makes the keyboard?

Comment: Hm, I don't know. Do you know how I can check that?

Comment: Maybe on the back there might be a model number or something like that.

Comment: There's nothing that's keyboard-specific on the back. I installed the `hardinfo` package and the keyboard is displayed as "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" by vendor "1". Does that help at all?...

Comment: Is there a driver or software for that keyboard that you know of?

Comment: No, not that I know of. I didn't install any drivers specific/custom drivers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, the Web is truly an amazing thing! After much research and diving into many forum links, I managed to better understand the problem, to find out what program was responsible for it and, finally, to disable this behavior for good. I thought I'd write down my steps, in case other people run into the same issue.

### Step 1. Monitor the system to know if/when the keyboard backlight is being turned on

The first thing is to know that the current status of the keyboard backlight can be checked by reading the file `/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness`. So, we would like to be notified of any changes to this file and, ideally, what process invoked the change.

This can be done using [fanotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html). I used the [example program](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html#EXAMPLE) that is provided in the man page and added a few modifications* so that I could monitor changes to the brightness file. Turns out that the process responsible for the modification was `/usr/lib/upower/upowerd`, which is a daemon process for [UPower](http://upower.freedesktop.org/).

### Step 2. Find out why UPower is turning the backlight on (fail)

This was the fuzziest part of the investigation, and I still can't tell why this happens. I found a person with a [*very* similar problem](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184187) but with no solution, so I started to see if I could just disable UPower completely (and what would the consequences be) when I found [this link](http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/disabling-battery-in-ubuntu-vms.html). Turns out UPower has a configuration file! That's better.

### Step 3. Stop UPower from turning on the keyboard backlight

Finally, I edited the aforementioned config file, located at `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UPower.conf`, and changed `<allow>` to `<deny>` in the following line:

```
<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
       send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>
```

I then restarted dbus with `sudo service dbus restart` (use `systemctl restart dbus.service` on Ubuntu 16.04 and later) and proceeded to lock my screen to test the result and... It worked!! Well, sorta. The login screen wouldn't show up, so I couldn't log back in and had to force a restart. But **then**  everything worked great!

And that's it! I'm still curious what would be the **right** way to do this. If you know, leave a comment, please!

* For instance, the example program was only set up to monitor `FAN_OPEN_PERM`and `FAN_CLOSE_WRITE` events, but in this it was an `FAN_MODIFY` event.

Comment: I just edited the file `org.freedesktop.UPower.conf ` as you specified, and it worked.  I think the change was applied immediately.

Comment: Thanks man :) it worked. you deserve a beer! what is your A/c number ;) for now handle this +1 cheers

Comment: @TheVOYOU Glad it worked for you! :)

Comment: This fix also works for 16.04, except for some reason I can't restart the dbus service anymore.  I had to reboot my laptop.