# Keyboard backlight set on maximum after screen is switched back on

Tags: dell, 15.10, keyboard-backlight

When I wake my laptop up after some time of inactivity when the screen turns off it turns back on and also the keyboard backlight is turned on on maximum. How can I keep the keyboard light off? Screen brightness is not affected.

I use Dell Inspiron 7520 and Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard backlight turns on after lock screen/display on](http://askubuntu.com/questions/700069/keyboard-backlight-turns-on-after-lock-screen-display-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700069/keyboard-backlight-turns-on-after-lock-screen-display-on) in the file `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UPower.conf` I changed `<allow>` to `<deny>` and it worked.

```
<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
   send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>
```